# UI Grid column defs get overridden

Tags: angularjs

On populating the UI Grid, the UI Grid column defs get overridden when the data has more fields. How to solve this? Where and how to solve this, in the controller, in the WEB Api ?

For simplicity no filtering in the sample is put:

```
<!-- View -->
<style>
 .myGrid { height: 300px; width: 1000px; border: 1px solid black;}
</style>

<div id="grid1" ui-grid="grid1Options"
 class="myGrid" ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-move-column ui-grid-pinning
 ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-selection ui-grid-save-state>
</div>

//Controller
(function () {
 'use strict';
  angular
    .module('pdb').controller('suppliersController_',
    ['$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants', '$resource', 'suppliersFactory_', 
      fSuppliersController_]);
    function fSuppliersController_($scope, $http, uiGridConstants, $resource, suppliersFactory_) 
    {
    $scope.grid1Options = { 
    enableSorting: true, enableFiltering: false, showGridFooter: false,
    showColumnFooter: false, enableColumnResizing: true, enableColumnMoving: true,
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true, enableRowSelection: true, enableSelectAll: true,
    selectionRowHeaderWidth: 35,
    columndefs: [
    { name: 'Name_Supplier', width: '40%', displayName: 'Supplier', field: 'Name_Supplier' },
    { name: 'Contact', width: '60%', displayName: 'Contact', field: 'Contact' }                 
    ]};
    (new suppliersFactory_())
    .$getAll()
    .then(function (result) { $scope.grid1Options.data = result.value; });
    }
})();

// Factory
(function () {
   'use strict';
    angular.module('pdb').factory('suppliersFactory_', 
    ['$resource', fSuppliersFactory_]);
    function fSuppliersFactory_($resource) {
        return $resource("", {}, { 'getAll': { method: "GET", url: "odata/Suppliers" } });
    }
})();

// Web API returns more fields..
public class SuppliersController : ODataController
{
  private PDBEntities db = new PDBEntities();
  // GET: odata/Suppliers
  [EnableQuery]
  public IQueryable<tblSupplier> GetSuppliers() { return db.tblSuppliers; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/commit/fd154a71f6a7407bce577efebde9f1122274c48b

Make sure you have `grid.lateBoundColumns` set to `false`.

This is an old issue, make sure you have a recent version of `ng-grid`.

From the author:

I see what the issue is,

> There is no data and no column definitions initially , so the grid
>   goes into a "waiting" state and has a flag set to automatically
>   generate the columns, then, even when you set the column definitions,
>   they get auto-generated when the data hits. I added a fix for it in
>   commit

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/285

http://jsfiddle.net/ShEB4/9/

Comment: Tnx for your reply. But does this also apply to UI grid? It is nog ng-grid I am using.

Comment: Ah whoops. No matter I suspect the issue is similar. Do you render the table at all *before* you get data, like with a "no data" messge? or does it only render after that?

Comment: In the sample above the binding: ..(new suppliersFactory_()).$getAll().. is started as soon as the controller is activated. So I made an adjustment to have it triggered by an ng-click and  I also added ...lateBoundColumns : false... but that does not seem work either.